# WordPress Conditional Statement Optimization

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress plugin I have the following hook which runs for every avatar on the page (comments, author, etc.).

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'the_function', 1, 5);
```

`the_function` has a conditional statement in it that is also run every time the function is run as well.

```
function the_function()
{
if(get_option('my option', 1) == 1){
echo 'true';
}
}
```

I don't know if out of scope would be the right term, but is there any logical way to retrieve the variable once and then store it when the function is called again when the file is still being in use to reduce the amount of calls to get the option and potentially minimize resources?

Comment: I don't have an official reference right now, but I'm pretty sure WP options are cached and available full time. This would be an unnecessary micro-optimization. If you're using OOP, you could store the value in a property.

Answer (score 0):

b__ might be right that WordPress caches the get options and therefor making it unnecessary to do micro optimization, but I have found a way for those who are doing this maybe in php or still want to store something themselves. To do so, make a variable outside your function in your php code and then call it in your function using global $yourvariable.